# udev rule not worknig as expected with PROGRAM key

Tags: linux, debian, linux-kernel, udev

My system is Debian Buster with Kernel 4.19. I have a simple udev rule as below that was working fine with Debian Jessie. Now same rule seems to be not working in newer distribution.

```
 KERNEL=="sd[a-z]1",SUBSYSTEM=="block",ACTION=="add|change",PROGRAM="/bin/lsblk --fs --noheadings -o FSTYPE $tempnode"

 RESULT=="ext4",SYMLINK+="working_stick"
```

this rule works fine with Debian Jessie and also on current distribution(Debian Buster) if I manually run "udevadm trigger" this rule works fine but in normal working scenario this rule doesn't come into play.

I am not sure what I am missing. I am providing logs for both error case and successful case.

---

**Log of udev when I find there is no symlink as per udev rule file:**

```
Oct 18 09:50:11 localhost systemd-udevd[28351]: sdb1: PROGRAM '/bin/lsblk --fs --noheadings -o FSTYPE /dev/sdb1' /etc/udev/rules.d/test.rules:19

Oct 18 09:50:11 localhost systemd-udevd[28351]: Starting '/bin/lsblk --fs --noheadings -o FSTYPE /dev/sdb1'

Oct 18 09:50:11 localhost systemd-udevd[28351]: Successfully forked off '(spawn)' as PID 30481.

Oct 18 09:50:11 localhost systemd-udevd[28351]: Process '/bin/lsblk --fs --noheadings -o FSTYPE /dev/sdb1' succeeded.
```

---

**Log of udev when I execute "udevadm trigger" manaually and I find that symlink is getting created :**

Oct 18 11:20:20 localhost systemd-udevd[3758]: '/bin/lsblk --fs --noheadings -o FSTYPE /dev/sdb1'(out) 'ext4'****

```
Oct 18 11:20:20 localhost systemd-udevd[3758]: Process '/bin/lsblk --fs --noheadings -o FSTYPE /dev/sdb1' succeeded.
```

---

So in a successful case there is one additional line in the log that says what the output of the command was written to RESULT.